# Minimum system requirements for mining ropsten ethers

Tags: ether, mining, ropsten, aws, faucets

I want to create my own faucet that will mine Ropsten ethers.

What is the minimum system configuration which is required? Is it a good idea to use my own server such as AWS? What will be the tentative cost? Can it be done with free tier AWS?

What else do I need to keep in mind when mining rETHs?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done it for a while, so hopefully, a kind spirit will chime in if I seem to be misleading you.

Mining on Ropsten is not very competitive. You can mine coins with CPU mining and I think you'll be successful with a free tier instance. Keep in mind that you might not be able to stay within the free tier limits if you run it 24/7.

CPU mining scales with cores/threads. After you sync your node with Ropsten, in `geth`, `miner.start(n)` where `n` is the number of cores to devote to mining - probably all of them.

You may get away with as little as 1 or 2 GB of RAM. 4 GB should be plenty. I'm uncertain today's disk requirement but I think 50 GB would be ample.

Hope it helps.